# Cannot find personal npm module

Tags: node.js, npm

I've got a personal node.js app (unicorn-deposit-lobby) which I'm trying to use as an npm dependency in another project. I've got it in my package.json, have done an npm install and can see it when I execute npm list however when I run it I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find module 'unicorn-deposit-lobby'
firefox
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sam.eeles/git/tempWebdriverIo/test/specs/desktop/test.js:1:87)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Could anyone help me, I can't understand why it can't find my module?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your main section in packages.json points correctly to the module entry point.  Or  use local path in require like

```
require('./moddir')
```